# When there is a certain text/value in a label then the code tells the computer to send an email to the person

Tags: vb.net, email, text

I am trying to make a system where if a certain value/text is in a label from an internet source then the computer sends me an email this is the code that i have got up to so far if any is incorrect or if you would be so kind as to retype out a new code for me so this works it would be marvellous! Thanks again your help is much appreciated as it is my GCSE project for IT. My code:

```
Imports System.Net.Mail
Public Class form2

Private Sub avsl_Load(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load


End Sub

Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

    If itemstock1.Text = "low" Then

        Try
            Dim emailmessage As New MailMessage
            emailmessage.From = New MailAddress("xxxxx.yyyyyy@outlook.com")
            emailmessage.To.Add("xxxx.zzzz@icloud.com")
            emailmessage.Subject = ("guitar hanger 180.175")
            emailmessage.Body = itemstock1.Text
            Dim SMTP As New SmtpClient("smtp.live.com")
            SMTP.Port = 587
            SMTP.EnableSsl = True
            SMTP.Credentials = New System.Net.NetworkCredential("zxzxz.yyy@outlook.com", "(my password)")
            SMTP.Send(emailmessage)
        Catch ex As Exception
        End Try
    ElseIf itemstock1.Text = "low" Then
        Me.Show()

    End If

End Sub

End Class
```

Comment: does it work?  what is the problem?

Comment: I need it to send an email when "low" is in the label text. But I have tried the code above and it doesn't work